# Set the expiry date of a blob or auto delete the blob after X number of days in Azure Storage using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I would like to automatically delete the blob in Azure Storage after certain days via code in C#. There are two options to do this:

1. Write your own timer trigger apps, iterate over the blobs whose last modified date is over X number of days and delete the blob.
2. Use Lifecycle management option available in Azure portal where we can add our rules to delete the blob in simple way

Is there any other way or any property available where we could implement the same functionality (set the expiry time/date while uploading the blob in azure storage) through the code in C#?

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can set to delete a blob after X days using Storage Lifecycle Management:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do we implement the same functionality through the code in C#?

Comment: @SarveshKulkarni, is this a `Hierarchical Namespace enabled account`(ADLS gen2)? if yes, it can be do it via code.

Comment: I could not find any sample about it using code. I guess, it's not available yet

Comment: @IvanYang how to find out if it is hierarchical namespace enabled account?

Comment: @SarveshKulkarni please check this doc: [Create a storage account with a hierarchical namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/create-data-lake-storage-account#create-a-storage-account-with-a-hierarchical-namespace). If the storage account already exists, then you can go to azure portal -> the storage account -> settings -> Configuration -> then check the `Data Lake Storage Gen2 Hierarchical namespace` option is enabled or not.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch/samples/Sample03b_BatchingAsync.cs#L22 may be helpful